# Group By + Aggregate + Count in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, count, aggregate, pandas-groupby

Imagine I have a table that contains employee sales information. For now, I am mainly interested in how many sales/customers each employee has. I am interested in both the total counts (how many total customers the employee has sold to) and the unique counts (how many unique customers the employee has sold to). To do this, I am looking at the `Employee_id` and `Customer_id` columns (although there are other columns as well) in the `Sales` dataset. They look something like this:

```
  | Employee_id | Customer_id
 1|      'E122' |      'C921' ...
 2|      'E122' |      'C221' ...
 3|      'E43'  |      'C365' ...
 4|      'E122' |      'C221' ...
 5|      'E57'  |      'C138' ...
 ...
```

Both columns contain strings to represent the ids. Right now, I have the following but I get an 'int' object is not callable error, and I don't know why.

```
Sales.groupby('Employee_id').agg({
'counts': [
    ('Customer_id', count)
]})
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and where the 'int' related error is coming from. I have typically seen aggregation functions like `sum` and `max`, but not as much with `count` so that could be the issue. Also, if I want to count unique customers as well, how would I do that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: look at nunique

Comment: Its a dupe, try df.groupby('Employee_id').agg(['count', 'nunique'])

Comment: @Wen nunique does not work if I change the current code from count to nunique. It says name 'nunique' not defined.

Comment: @Vaishali thank you! I just added single quotes to my current code (instead of count, I did 'count') and that worked.